# Error while trying to query two tables with UNION ALL

Tags: php, mysql, union, multiple-tables

I'm trying to query a single result from two tables in my database. Here is my code:

```
$pageid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$query = sprintf("(SELECT * FROM classifieds WHERE pageid = '$pageid' LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM resumes WHERE pageid = '$pageid' LIMIT 1)");
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['title'] . "<br/>";
    }
```

`pageid` is a URL variable. This code is trying to use that variable, query the database with it, and return the result. I get this error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource
```

Hitting a wall here. Can't figure out why this error keeps happening. Any help == thanks.

Comment: You should check if your $result is empty.  Also, from a console try to run the query and see if you are getting any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `UNION` the number of columns and types of columns, of both queries must be same.

Now as you are quering two different tables, I guess it is safe to assume that either number of columns are different or corresponding column types do not match.

try using something like this

```
select col1, col2 from classifieds.......
Union All
select col1, col2
```

but again, number and corresponding column types should be same.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is the problem he gets, too :)

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Number of columns and types were different. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Execute your query directly and see if it returns any rows. BTW, what is the use of sprintf?

Answer (score 0):

Add this error handling to your code:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

The execution of your query failed, as a result `$result` was set to `false` which is not a valid MySQL result resource and hence the error.

Once possible cause of the problem is that the two tables have unequal number of columns. `UNION ALL` expects its sub queries to return equal number of columns.

Comment: I didn't know this, and it would've been helpful. Thanks.